# Images are not loading after Transferred Laravel Website on server

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have transferred website from local to web server, mean while i changed some scenarios.

1- I have changed folder structure and moved public folder files on root.

2- Image files are being uploaded into store folder while symbolic storage folder is moved on root also.

But after moving public folder files on root images not working. while uploaded images are being stored into main storage folder. but not linked with symbolic storage folder. so help me how can i attach again both storage folders.

Storage folder related code into config/filesystem is shown below:

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/pulic/images/'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET'),
        'region' => env('AWS_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
    ],

],
```

main storage folder path is:

```
Root/Laravel_files/storage/app/public/images
```

while symbolic storage folder address is:

```
Root/storage/images
```